# Codeigniter 2 join one-to-many query 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, codeigniter-2

I have 3 tables

`table1: documents (id, code, content)`

`table2: files (id, code, filename)`

`table3: tags (documentId, tag)`

On my page, I have to display all the documents in a table view. like

`code    | content`

`123  | This is a sample document with file **files.filename** and tags **tags.tag**`

Each document can have many files and tags

This is my current code.

```
return $this->db
    ->select('t1.id, t1.barcode, t1.sub, t1.source_type, t1.sender, t1.address, t1.description, t1.receipient, t1.status, t2.id as fileId, t3.tag as docTag')
    ->select('DATE_FORMAT(t1.datetime_added, \'%m/%d/%Y-%h:%i %p\') as datetime_added', FALSE)
    ->from('documents as t1')
    ->join('files as t2', 't2.barcode = t1.barcode', 'left')
    ->join('tags as t3', 't3.id = t1.id')
    ->order_by('id', 'desc')
    ->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Can you please tell us the part that is not working

Comment: if one document have 3 file,or tags, then the document will show for 3 time or for one time???

Comment: @Luca, like what Dani is asking, if I have tags, it returns 3 rows. It should only return 1 row with docTag in array (maybe)

Comment: @Dan, the document should only return 1 row instead of 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this query it will help you

```
SELECT `doc`.`id`,
       (select GROUP_CONCAT(`tag`) from `tags` `tag` where `docid`=`doc`.`id` group by `docid`) as `tags`, 
      (select GROUP_CONCAT(`filename`)  from `files` where `docid`=`doc`.`id` group by `docid`) as `file`
FROM `document` `doc`
```

if you have more files or tags for document it will show one record from document table,tags and file name will be comma separated if multi

Comment: Sir @Dani, I will try this and give you update. Thanks

Comment: You always welcome. If you have any issue let me know i will right the code for you

Comment: Many thanks, @Dani! It's now working. I have another query similar to this with where clause. I guess I have to post as another question. Again, thank you

Answer (score 0):

change this line:`->join('tags as t3', 't3.id = t1.id')` to

```
->join('tags as t3', 't3.documentid = t1.id') .
```

Also specify a table while an order by query:

```
  ->order_by('t1.id', 'desc').
```

Hope it helps?